# get max date when sum of a field equals a value

Tags: sql

I have a problem with writing a query.
Row data  is as follow :

```
DATE        CUSTOMER_ID AMOUNT
20170101    1           150
20170201    1           50
20170203    1           200
20170204    1           250
20170101    2           300
20170201    2           70
```

I want to know when(which date) the sum of amount for each customer_id  becomes  more than 350,
How can I write this query to have such a result ?

```
CUSTOMER_ID   MAX_DATE
1             20170203
2             20170201
```

Thanks,

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use ANSI/ISO standard window functions to calculate the running sum:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             sum(t.amount) over (partition by t.customer_id order by t.date) as running_amount
      from t
     ) t
where running_amount - amount < 350 and
      running_amount >= 350;
```

If for some reason, your database doesn't support this functionality, you can use a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             (select sum(t2.amount)
              from t t2
              where t2.customer_id =  t.customer_id and
                    t2.date <= t.date
             ) as running_amount
      from t
     ) t
where running_amount - amount < 350 and
      running_amount >= 350;
```

Answer (score 1):

ANSI SQL

Used for the test: TSQL and MS SQL Server 2012

> ```
> select 
>   "CUSTOMER_ID",
>   min("DATE")
> FROM
> (
>  select 
>   "CUSTOMER_ID",
>   "DATE",
>   (
>   SELECT 
>     sum(T02."AMOUNT") AMOUNT
>   FROM "TABLE01" T02
>   WHERE
>      T01."CUSTOMER_ID" = T02."CUSTOMER_ID"
>      AND T02."DATE" <= T01."DATE"
>   ) "AMOUNT"
>  from "TABLE01" T01
> ) T03
> where
>   T03."AMOUNT" > 350
> group by
>   "CUSTOMER_ID"
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> CUSTOMER_ID | (No column name)   
> ----------: | :------------------
>           1 | 03/02/2017 00:00:00
>           2 | 01/02/2017 00:00:00
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=b7df90a86be58f9920e449ae042f5392)*

Answer (score 0):

[DB-Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/scdonWTiqPm9zzGxNLTAbi/0)

```
SELECT
    tmp.`CUSTOMER_ID`,
    MIN(tmp.`DATE`) as MAX_DATE
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            `DATE`,
            `CUSTOMER_ID`,
            `AMOUNT`,
            (
                SELECT SUM(`AMOUNT`) FROM tbl t2 WHERE t2.`DATE` <= t1.`DATE` AND `CUSTOMER_ID` = t1.`CUSTOMER_ID`
            ) AS SUM_UP
        FROM
            `tbl` t1
        ORDER BY
            `DATE` ASC
   ) tmp
WHERE
    tmp.`SUM_UP` > 350
GROUP BY
    tmp.`CUSTOMER_ID`
```

**Explaination:**

First I select all rows and subselect all rows with SUM and ID where the current row DATE is smaller or same as all rows for the customer. From this tabe i select the MIN date, which has a current sum of >350

Comment: Please read question again and compare result what is expected @Pilan

Comment: Just noticed :) Working on it!

Comment: Sort of same answer, but Your SUM will apply across all records, so you need to use HAVING...

Comment: Thanks a lot,but what I mean is getting the date when  a customer_ID reachs the goal,for examole customer_id=1 reach the goal (35) in 20170203,but your query result is 20170204 for this customer

Comment: @VincentVancalbergh dear, i understand that you want the first date of when total amount greater than 350. Is it right ? If you look for last date this answer is correct but i think that you want the first date.

Comment: @Waayd I didn't ask the question, also, your current answer is different from when I posted my comment.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not an easy calculation and you have to calculate something. I know It could be seen a little mixed but i want to calculate step by step. As fist step if we can get success for your scenario, I believe it can be made better about performance. *If anybody can make better my query please edit my post;*

Unfortunately the solution that i cannot try on computer is below, I guess it will give you expected result;

```
-- Get the start date of customers
SELECT MIN(DATE) AS DATE
    ,CUSTOMER_ID
INTO #table
FROM TABLE t1

-- Calculate all possible date and where is sum of amount greater than 350
SELECT t1.CUSTOMER_ID
    ,SUM(SELECT Amount FROM TABLE t3 WHERE t3.DATE BETWEEN t1.DATE
            AND t2.DATE) AS total
    ,t2.DATE AS DATE
INTO #tableCalculated
FROM #table t1
INNER JOIN TABLE t2 ON t.ID = t2.ID
    AND t1.DATE != t2.DATE
WHERE total > 350

-- SELECT Min amount and date for per Customer_ID
SELECT CUSTOMER_ID, MIN(DATE) AS DATE
FROM #tableCalculated
GROUP BY ID
```

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT CUSTOMER_ID, MIN(DATE) AS GOALDATE
FROM ( SELECT cd1.*, (SELECT SUM(AMOUNT)
                 FROM CustData cd2
                 WHERE cd2.CUSTOMER_ID = cd1.CUSTOMER_ID
                   AND cd2.DATE <= cd1.DATE) AS RUNNINGTOTAL
  FROM CustData cd1) AS custdata2
WHERE RUNNINGTOTAL >= 350
GROUP BY CUSTOMER_ID
```

[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6edVzsRu2goyWeRNisSx4w/0)

Comment: Thanks a lot,but what I mean is getting the date when  a customer_ID reachs the goal,for examole customer_id=1 reach the goal (35) in 20170203,but your query result is 20170204 for this customer

Comment: @user3577606 Could you please verify my answer once more? I changed it. Even though it seems you already have a working one.